# Date Test not working - namespace issue?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

In the xslt below my code is always going into the otherwise (ohno tags) no matter what condition I use (greater than, less than or equals to).  Seems strange that none of those conditions could be true when the dates do have values.  Is there maybe something I'm missing with the xs namespace because it doesn't seem to recognize format-date functions even though it's xslt 2.0.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            version="2.0">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/"> 
    <Hi>
        <Start><xsl:value-of select="'Starting'"/></Start>

        <xsl:call-template name="DayFunction">
            <xsl:with-param name="EndDate" as="xs:date"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <End><xsl:value-of select="'End Here'"/></End>
    </Hi>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="DayFunction" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:param name="pEndDate" as="xs:date" select="'2017-05-20'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vStartDate" as="xs:date" select="'2017-05-01'" />

    <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$pEndDate &gt;= $vStartDate">
            <ok><xsl:value-of select="$pEndDate"/></ok>
            <xsl:call-template name="DayFunction">
                <xsl:with-param name="EndDate" select="$pEndDate - xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>    
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <ohno><xsl:value-of select="$pEndDate"/></ohno>
            <ohno><xsl:value-of select="$vStartDate"/></ohno>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose> 
    <after>2</after>    
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Ah, nm I just did  a system-property('xsl:version') and see it's 1.0.

Comment: If you are no longer seeking an answer to the question, then it is within your power to delete it as long as there is no upvoted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to correct a couple of details:

- `xmlns:xs="..."` should be placed in `stylesheet` tag, not in `template`.
- If a `param` has a type (`as="xs:date"`) then the default value should
  also be given as `xs:date`, not as a string. Change it to
  `xs:date('2017-05-20')`.
- The same applies to `vStartDate`.
- The call to `DayFunction` template should have parameter name the same
  like in the template declaration. Change `EndDate` to `pEndDate`
  (note missing *p* in `with-param`, in 2 places).
- When you supply a parameter to a template call, you must write also
  its value. Apparently you forgot about `select` in `with-param`.
- `value-of` with a constant string argument between starting and ending
  tags (e.g. `<Start><xsl:value-of select="'Starting'"/></Start>`) is
  a weird construction. Write just `<Start>Starting</Start>`.
  It works much quicker.

Below you have a working script (with result as expected).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/"> 
    <Hi>
      <Start>Starting</Start>
      <xsl:call-template name="DayFunction">
        <xsl:with-param name="pEndDate" select="xs:date('2017-05-20')"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <End>End Here</End>
    </Hi>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="DayFunction">
    <xsl:param name="pEndDate" as="xs:date" select="xs:date('2017-05-20')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vStartDate" as="xs:date" select="xs:date('2017-05-01')" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$pEndDate &gt;= $vStartDate">
        <ok><xsl:value-of select="$pEndDate"/></ok>
        <xsl:call-template name="DayFunction">
          <xsl:with-param name="pEndDate" select="$pEndDate - xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>    
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <ohno><xsl:value-of select="$pEndDate"/></ohno>
        <ohno><xsl:value-of select="$vStartDate"/></ohno>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose> 
    <after>2</after>    
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```